# Scrollable dynamic content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am building a custom lightbox with jquery and am wondering what to do when I need to scroll the form as this is a responsive site. On some screen sizes the form grows below the fold but when I go to scroll the page the site behind it scrolls instead. How do I put focus on the new dynamic content for scrollability?

[www.evoke.me](http://evoke.me)

Click the contact button after scrolling down the page a bit.

Here is the code I am working with.

```
$('#contact').on( 'click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal').remove();
        $('body').append('<div id="modal"></div>');
        $("#modal").load('/forms/contact-form.html').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});

#modal{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:0;
    z-index:5000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .95) url(../images/diag-pattern.png) repeat 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you having difficulty? Please do not post a link and say "*how do I do x?*"

Comment: Geez... Didn't really think I needed to show the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not getting focus on the dynamic content.  The problem is that the content is not scrollable because you used `position: fixed` without `overflow: auto`.  To make the contact form scrollable, add `overflow: auto` to your css for `#modal`.

Comment: This is helpful. Now I am getting two scroll bars. Is it possible to maintain only one like a typical lightbox? Maybe this is better for a chat convo.

Comment: @user980988 - When the modal is visible, set `overflow: hidden` on `body`.